# Firestore Permission Rule Ignoring roles in parent collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a simple firestore rule that only allows create if the user is an admin in the parent document. The parent document looks like this:

```
{
  ...,
  roles: {
    uid: 'admin'
  }
}
```

The rule I am attempting to use is this

```
    match /cookbooks/{cookbookId}/{document=**} {
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cookbooks/$(cookbookId)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == 'admin'
    }
```

This does not work but weirdly enough if I do

```
    match /cookbooks/{cookbookId}/{document=**} {
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cookbooks/$(cookbookId)).data.roles != null
    }
```

that works. So that leads me to believe its getting the roles but then I have no idea why the first rule wouldnt work. I have triple checked that my firestore data is correct and has my uid in the roles object with the value 'admin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you indeed putting the values of the uids in the parent document in place of the `uid` in your example? Like with `uid = 123` it would become

```
{
  ...,
  roles: {
    123: 'admin'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to get the data directly from the `uid` like this:

```js
match /cookbooks/{cookbookId}/{document=**} {
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cookbooks/$(cookbookId)/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data == 'admin'
    }
```

Comment: This cannot work, there is no /roles/{uid} document

Comment: Sorry. From the question you wrote it looks like that it does exist. Can you share a more detailed example of your database and structure. Try next time to explain your question better and not do downvote ppl that try to help you.